# Django Web application publishing

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

How to publish django web application? what are the steps to be followed for publishing a django application? is there any free hosting for pulishing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using PythonAnyWhere for hosting my project. They provide hosting for python-Django / flask specificly and have a very dedicated team.

You can host your app for free but you can not use your own domain. To use custom domain, you need to purchase paid plan starting from $5 per month.

Their customer support is extremly good.

**Steps to follow for hosting:**
 - Make sure your code is production ready i.e. well tested and bug free.
 - Separate production and dev settings file. On production you need to set `DEBUG=false`.
 - Push your code to github. Do not commit sensitive information like credentials or api keys. Keep them in .env file.
 - Create account on pythonanywhere server and create database.
 - Clone the git repo. Complete the web setup step. Edit the wsgio settings file.
 - Run migrations. `python manage.py migrate`.
 - Create cache table if any `python manage.py createcachetable`.
 - Collect static files `python manage.py collectstatic`.
 - Reload the web app.

Refer [this step by step article](https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/18/how-to-host-django-app-on-pythonanywhere-for-free/) to setup a free account and host web app on pythonanywhere server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of Amazon Web Services if you want simplicity and automation. You can create a CodeStar project for Django and Elastic Beanstalk. Everything is set up from you, so as soon as you commit code to your github repo (it even can create the repo for you with the elastic beanstalk config files), it builds, tests, then deploys it.

The best part is you can utilize amazon's free-tier level if you are a new member so it's probably going to be free or extremely cheap.

Look here for reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/codestar/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

digitalocean.com is good for hosting. [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I used this for Django 2.0 with python3.

Comment: Is it free ?? But asking for card details.

Comment: No it's not free but it's extremely cost efficient. What do you me you're asking for card details?